# Ensure Interchangeability of JavaScript-Frontend at build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, vue.js, software-product-lines

I have got defined REST-Endpoints for which I want to develop interchangeable JavaScript Frontends (Vue.js or React). This means depending on the customer's wishes there shall be a different Frontend. As the REST-Endpoint is defined the set of data that can be submitted is defined. Of course, there is a server-side validation of the data. So, if a customer specific frontend is developed and this frontend wants to submit data that cannot be handled by the REST-Endpoints this will produce an error. However, if the fronted contains wrong input fields because the developer made an error, this error will occur at runtime. I am looking for a way to detect errors at build time.

I want a defined backend for which different developers can create customised frontends. Those frontends shall be tested before being deployed so that they will work with the REST-Endpoints.

It shall be tested, if only data is submitted that can be handled by the backend. However, it shall be possible to submit a subset of the data that can be handled by the REST-Endpoints.

In summary I want to have different Implementations of the frontend. If I wanted to develop different Implementations in the backend I would use Interfaces and would develop different Implementation of this Interface. So, I would create a contract that assures that always the same paramets are passed.

Is there a way to create Interfaces for example with React or Vue.js to enforce the use of the predefined parameters? Or would it be better to write unit tests, that check if the submit request contains more than the allowed parameters? If so, how can I write those unit tests once and apply them to all interchangeable frontends?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: *Is there a way to create Interfaces for example with React or Vue.js to enforce the use of the predefined parameters?* - this is what TS is for, to detect such mistakes at build time. You are free to validate and normalize data at runtime as well. These parts aren't supposed to depend on the framework and could be shared between apps.

Comment: In addition to TypeScript, you might find value in spending some time researching data validation, and unit testing vs integration testing.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have thought of TypeScript, too. However, I am not sure, if it possible to create an interface for a component. As far as I have understoot you can create interfaces for datastructures and then I can use those datastructures. This would be a workaround. I would need to enforce the usage of this datastructure by company policy. However, I would prefer a technical enforcement so that it cannot be built without implementing the interface.

Comment: @jsejcksn can you clarify or give me some more hint what you mean with data validation. I am aware that of course I can validate data. Both in frontend and in backend. The validation already works in the backend. However, if the frontend developer do not validate the data I have no technical opportunity to enforce the frontend validation. Furthermore, I do know the difference between unit testing and integration testing. But I do not know how this difference would help me with my question.

Comment: You need to enforce data structure in the place where data is sent. In order to guarantee this components need to be implemented with proper types. If a component cheats request API that form data conforms the interface but it actually isn't then the error will occur at runtime. It's unclear what exactly your case is and whether you have control over the usage of interfaces in components. The question is too vague and isn't well-suited for SO. But basically TS at build time and/or validation at runtime (schema validation like joi, yup) are your options. Also TS doesn't prevent excessive params